# Add items to product cart using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i would like to add a product to a product cart using the following code:

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service()     
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         

  link = "https://www.farmaline.be/pharmacie/commander/davitamon-more-energy-3-in-1-11-gratuit/" 
  driver.get (link)     
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'(//input[@x-model="quantity"])[3]'))).clear()
  time.sleep(1)
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'(//input[@x-model="quantity"])[3]'))).send_keys("50")     
  time.sleep(1)    
  waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@title="Ajouter au panier"]'))).click()    
  driver.quit()
```

But when i run the program i get a TimeoutException:

```
$ python temp1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\tijsengel\temp1.py", line 30, in <module>
    waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@title="Ajouter au panier"]'))).click()
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Why is this not working?

When i inspect the site with and use the xpath

```
//button[@title="Ajouter au panier"]
```

i can find this element.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause of the issue:** XPATH expression `//button[@title="Ajouter au panier"]` is locating more than one element, see below:

[image]

Hence your script is not able to locate correct element and failing with `TimeOutException`

**Solution:** Change the XPATH expression as below, this will locate the first following `<button>` node.

```
(//input[@x-model="quantity"])[3]//following::button[1]
```

**Refer working code below:**

```
link = "https://www.farmaline.be/pharmacie/commander/zaffranax-stress-fatigue/"
driver.get (link)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//input[@x-model="quantity"])[3]'))).clear()
time.sleep(1)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//input[@x-model="quantity"])[3]'))).send_keys("50")
time.sleep(1)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@x-model="quantity"])[3]//following::button[1]'))).click()
driver.quit()
```

**Note:** You may notice that I have changed the URL, this is because the product you are searching has run out of stock in the website. So I have changed the URL to search another product.